# Server access through two different wifi routers

Tags: networking, wifi, samba, router

I have a wifi home-network setup. I have a linux server, and couple of linux devices, but most of the others in my home use windows computers.

My 'use case' seems simple enough to me, but may require explanation. I have two wifi-routers, thus two wifi networks.

wifi-1 (wifi router #1) is my standard connection. wifi-2 (wifi router #2) is used for VPN connection.

Right now, wifi-2 (internal ip = 192.168.1.1) is the only wireless device connected to my server. I want to also connect wifi-1 (internal ip = 192.168.0.1) to the server. **How do I do this?**

-- Additional info --

Also, I am NOT seeking to "port forward" either router as I want to keep the two different routers distinct. Some media-streaming services (hulu, netflix) do not allow the use of a VPN connection so I want to be able to choose which wireless network I connect to, but still want access to the home server from both. 
Another reason I want server access from either device is for network-printing. Wireless printers can only connect to one wireless network. I want my printers managed by the server and accessible whether I am on wifi-1 or wifi-2.
Lastly, not sure if this is necessary info, but one of my routers (wifi-1) is actually a modem/router combo. So for internet access I have only the two devices. Router #2 is plugged into my server via ethernet cable. Router #2 is also plugged into one of the out ports on Router #1.

INTERNET FEED ---> ROUTER #1 <-----> ROUTER #2 ---> SERVER

Answer (score 2):

> Router #2 is also plugged into one of the out ports on Router #1

If this is the case devices on connected to router1 should be able to access the server if you add a static route in router1's routing table and make the appropriate changes to router2's firewall (or turn it off completely).  In order to provide further guidance you'll need to provide the model of both routers and the "WAN" address of router2.  This would not impact the usage model of internet services for devices connected to router1.

Comment: Thanks for the offer to help. I'm not entirely sure where to access the "routing table" on router 1, but the model of both routers are: 
Router #1: Zoom modem/router combo, model 5352.
Router #2: Belkin F7D3302 / F7D7302 v1, now flashed with dd-wrt interface.
WAN ADDR, Router #2: 94:44:52:B7:55:5E

Comment: Researching the Zoom modem/router, I'm not sure there is a way to modify the routing table.  It does have an option to use the modem/router combo as a simple bridge.  Using this configuration you could then put a third dd-wrt router between (current) router1 and router2 and use it to route between the two subnets.